# Android Emulator won't start up (Faulting module: msvcrt.dll)

Tags: windows, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, vcredist

I set up Android Studio and create new AVD in it, but it won't start at all.
Event viewer in Windows returns following error, but I do not know what should I do with it:

[image]

```
Me specs:
Win 10 Enterprise / 
i7-4700MQ / 
32GB RAM / 
NVIDIA Quadro K1100M
```

Tried these AVDs: `API 24/25/26, Graphics Auto/Software, RAM 512/1536`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I figured it out - to run AVD you need to **start Android Studio as Administrator**.

Yeap, that's simple...